# How to handle an "Input CRS error" when clipping?

Tags: qgis, clip

I'm trying to clip a soil use shapefile, with a polygon I've created this morning. The clipping function works, but the clipped polygon doesn't have features (the table of contents is empty). QGIS advices me that:

*Created output shapefile:
/Users/biaginisandra/Desktop/Uso_suolo_Roncacce/Uso_suolo_Roncacce.shp
Warnings:
Input CRS error: One or more input layers missing coordinate reference information, results may not be as expected.
GEOS geoprocessing error: One or more input features have invalid geometry.
Some output geometries may be missing or invalid.
Would you like to add the new layer anyway?*

Where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a feeling that your soil use and clipping shapefile don't share the same coordinate system even though you're defining both to be the same. Did you create the clipping shapefile directly from the soil use one, or is it based on a different shapefile?

Answer (score 3):

"Defining" a CRS with `Set CRS for layer` is not enough for clipping, because clipping is an external command.

The shapefiles must have the same CRS. That can be applied with `rightclick -> Save as...` under a different name, but same CRS for both shapefiles.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that one or more input layers are missing coordinate reference information. So you probably should define CRS for your input layers, and then try again.

Comment: I have defined the CRS each time. But it didn't works. There's the same advice for clipping operations with regional polygons (created by the county) but after all I don't have these problems by working with them. It's all about the boundaries I create with "New Shapefile"